# Exporting the lint list to HTML in Android Studio does not replace my index.html with the lint issues

Tags: android, html, lint

Here are the things I did

Android Studio -> Analyze -> Inspect Code

Then it will run lint and gives a list of lint issues. Then I click export -> html

There is a dialog asking me for a location. Here are the two ways I check this.

1. Gives a location with a blank index.html file -> after export still blank
2. Gives a location with no index.html -> gives the file does not exist error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: It gives an arrayoutofboundexception in the event log

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I'm facing similar issue...

Comment: I couldn't. If you find a fix please add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using exporting action inside Inspection results not reliable .. I would suggest to run that test via terminal:

```
./gradlew lint
```

In the root of your project. You can specify it for BuildType or Flavor like:
For debug only:

```
./gradlew lintDebug
```

For flavor called `flavorname` only:

```
./gradlew lintFlavorname
```

report url will be printed after test has been completed.

I hope that may help,'.